# Let T be a spanning tree of a connected graph G..

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $T$ be a spaning tree of a connected graph $G$ and let $e$ be an edge of $G$ not in $T$.Show that $T+e$ contains a unique cycle.

So we know that if $T$ is spanning tree $\rightarrow$ $T$ is maximally acyclic, which means adding any edge will create a cycle, $\rightarrow$ $T+e$ creates a cycle. We can assume by contradiction that $T+e$ is not unique cycle which means that $\exists$ another cycle which is a contradiction, since spanning tree $T$ does not have any loops or cycles, since removing one edge from spanning tree will make the graph disconnected, since spanning tree is minimally connected.

I don't know if this is enough to say that i "solved" this problem, maybe i should add something more?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly, but close.  you need to prove e forms a cycle as well.  It is pretty simple, but it is necessary.  (also T+e contains a unique cycle, not is a unique cycle)

Comment: also need to show that the vertices that e connects only have one common parent so that it only creates one cycle.  All of this is quite easy, but necessary.  

1.  there wasnt a cycle b4

2.  the edge creates exactly 1 cycle

Comment: So we know that if $T$ is spanning tree $\rightarrow$ $T$ is maximally acyclic, which means adding any edge will create a cycle, $\rightarrow$ $T+e$ creates a cycle. We can assume by contradiction that $T+e$ is not unique cycle which means that $\exists$ another cycle which is a contradiction, since spanning tree $T$ does not have any loops or cycles, since removing one edge from spanning tree will make the graph disconnected, since spanning tree is minimally connected. That would be enough?

Comment: (sorry for formatting, still getting used to stack)  That is most likely good enough, ya.  i would of said assume T+e has more then 1 unique cycle while T has no cycle, These unique cycles must all use e.  so for e to be an edge from node A to B that has 2 unique cycles through it, there must be 2 unique paths from A to B without e.  this would mean there is a cycle through these two paths that does not have e in it, which is a contradiction.